# Use glob to match pattern in string in python

Tags: python, glob

I have a glob pattern that i am trying to use to match and pick some file. I am testing it and it seems to only work on the wild card. The example of files is as below which includes other files not listed but a different extension and that I do not need;

```
240721_124607_1000_Y1_B.txt.bz2
240721_124607_1000_Z1_B.txt.bz2
240721_124607_1000_X1_B.txt.bz2
```

The glob pattern that i am using gets all the files with the bz2 extension i.e

```
files = glob.glob('Z:/{}/{}/DL/*.txt.bz2'.format(directory, folder))
```

The above works but I want to narrow down to get only the ZI files. I have tried the following patterns but they do not work

```
files = glob.glob('Z:/{}/{}/DL/?Z1.txt.bz2'.format(directory, folder))
```

and  also tried

```
files = glob.glob('Z:/{}/{}/DL/Z1*.txt.bz2'.format(directory, folder))
```

and  also tried

```
files = glob.glob('Z:/{}/{}/DL/?Z1*.txt.bz2'.format(directory, folder))
```

All the above do not work.

Comment: `*ZI*.txt.bz2` ? maybe?  `?` matches exactly 1 character ... and it looks like there is more than that

Comment: that works great. are you able to answer the question so i can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` matches a single character, `*` matches any number of characters (even none). Since you're looking to match any name that includes `Z1`, the expression you need is this:

```
files = glob.glob('Z:/{}/{}/DL/*Z1*.txt.bz2'.format(directory, folder))
```

Mind you, this will also match anything like

```
Z1_Y1_B.txt.bz2
2407Z1_124607_1000_Y1_B.txt.bz2
2407Z1_124607_1000_X1_Z1.txt.bz2
etc.
```

As long as there's a `Z1` in there before the `.txt.bz2` and after the last slash, it will match